# Minimum Date Formula

Tags: visualforce, formula, date

Hoping this is an easy one. I have this formula in a VF page:

```
MIN(
     Year(DateValue(Account.CreatedDate)),
     Year(Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c),
     Year(DateValue(Account.Wellspring_Create_Date__c)),
     Year(Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c)
)
```

It is working well, but the problem is that it is picking up the blanks. I am trying to get rid of the blanks by using `BLANKVALUE` or `NULLVALUE`, but they return this error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'NULLVALUE()'. Expected Number, received Date

I'm sure there is a way to solve this, and there is probably a built in function. But I can't find it.

edit: I even tried:

```
MIN(
    Year(DateValue(Account.CreatedDate)),
    Year(DateValue(Account.Wellspring_Create_Date__c)),
    IF(ISBLANK(Year(Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c)),
        TODAY(),
        Year(Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c)),
   IF(ISBLANK(Year(Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c)),
        TODAY(),
        Year(Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c))
)
```

And I get this error:

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for function 'MIN()'. Expected Number, received **MISSING LABEL** PropertyFile - val null not found in section FormulaFieldExceptionDataTypes

It is worth to note that not all fields are datetime.

Comment: Try this - MIN(
    Year(DateValue(Account.CreatedDate)),
    Year(DateValue(Account.Wellspring_Create_Date__c)),
    Year(IF( ISBLANK(Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c),
              TODAY(),
              Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c)
        ),
    Year(IF( ISBLANK(Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c),
             TODAY(),
             Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c)
        )
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, by @kurunve:

```
MIN( 
     Year(DateValue(Account.CreatedDate)),
     Year(DateValue(Account.Wellspring_Create_Date__c)),
     Year(
          IF( ISBLANK(Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c),
             TODAY(), 
             Account.Source_System_Created_Date__c) ),
     Year(
          IF( ISBLANK(Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c),
             TODAY(),
             Account.Peoplesoft_Create_Date__c) )
    )
```

Putting the YEAR() function outside of the IF() function solved it. I don't know why.